# Trying for an SQL query in MySQL to exclude adjacent record duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySQL5.1.51 (in coldfusion 9 though I don't think that makes a difference) I have the following query

```
<cfquery datasource='localReferralData' name="getFiles">
SELECT messageID, patientsex, dateSent, patientTitle,
patientFirstname, patientLastname
FROM messages
WHERE filedata is not null
AND datesent > {ts '2012-03-10 00:00:02'}
AND deleted = 0
ORDER BY messageID DESC
</cfquery>
```

filedata is a blob of an rtf file. Files are transmitted to a receiving server by FTP and then parsed using POI to abstract the persons identifiers (title firstname lastname etc). Each file as it is picked up at the server is given a unique messageId (autonumber). Occasionally the sender will resend the file twice, usually one after another, however the blobs will still be identical.

I would like some way of the query only showing the first record of duplicate adjacent records.

Comment: is there a unique primary key? or are duplicates exact duplicates?

Comment: How are you defining "adjacent"?  Are you ordering by datesent (which I'm guessing is a datetime field)?  Or perhaps, ordering by datesent after ignoring deleted records?  And if they are non-adjacent, do you want to keep them?

Comment: Primary key is messageID. Ordering is by messageID. What I mean by adjacent is sequential messageID (autonumber) records. If there is 3 sends of the same file i.e. 3 identical blobs I just want the first listed.

Answer (score 0):

Group by blob, and take the minimum of the messageIds in each group.